# Jsp form submit get the dynamic response for defense on transaction complete

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

My web application , i am submitting jsp page, after submit four transaction committed , i need to get  dynamic response in every transaction complete.
 example.

first transaction completed(server side) -> first transaction complete response to jsp page(client side)

any one help me?

i have used only for jsp and servlet.

Comment: you suppose to use client side technologies like `jquery` with `ajax`. send each transaction one by one.